# How to send read-only data in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I must send copy of Form1 object to my method where I don't want to other users can change my actual data. How can I do it?

This must be something like that...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1 getGameData()
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1 = this;

        return form1;
    }
}
```

and I will use it as below...

```
someObject.someMethod(getGameData());
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are looking for.

Comment: You shouldn't be passing your actual form around then... create another class object to hold the data you want to pass and pass _that_ around.

Comment: @JeffMercado can you show example please.

Comment: Or make `Form1` a struct and it will automatically happen.

Comment: could you be more specific ? do you want a read only form to show ? or you want object copy of the form ?

Comment: What you're doing is extremely not recommended. Do what @JeffMercado stated. Create another Class with your game data and pass it around.

Comment: @GSerg: Are you just trying to bury him now?  :P  (p.s., that wouldn't work since he'd want to inherit from `Form`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a class from the data in the form and pass that class to your other method.

Map each of the fields from your form to this new class and then pass it wherever you need to access that data

Comment: @faridmovsumov Your question is "How can I pass copy of object...". You can't pass a copy without making a copy.

Comment: @faridmovsumov You won't be copying, you will be mapping. The read-only wrapper will return values from the underlying object, to which it will have access, and the caller won't.

Answer (score 1):

Let `Form1` implement an interface that defines read only access to your data, and then define the type of the parameter in your method to that interface.

```
oublic interface IMyInterface
{
    int Property1 { get; }
    int Property2 { get; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form, IMyInterface
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int Property1 { get; set; }
    int Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeMethod(IMyInterface readOnlyForm)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you just provide the instance of your form to `SomeClass.SomeMethod`